# How to describe logical paths that includes looking inside zip and tar.gz files?

Tags: path, filesystems, compression

I want to build a list of all the files on a large disk that includes the files that are inside container formats like tar files and zip files.

So I'd like to know if there already exists a notation for describing what you might call "logical" filesystem paths, which includes looking inside zip and tar.gz files?

For example, if I had a directory named a.dir that includes the file b.zip, and that file was a compressed version of b.txt, then then I'd imagine a notation that could describe the location of b.txt that would look something like

```
a.dir/b.zip/b.txt
```

However, I am not sure if that would always work, and it doesn't really tell you that b.zip is a zip file.

I am looking for a simple syntax that will identify common compression/container formats (zip, tar, tar.gz, tar.bz2, etc), handle nested compressed files, and handle compressed files with absolute or relative paths. Paths must uniquely identify one file (there can be no ambiguity.) Should work across a range of filesystems. Identifying symlinks would be a bonus.

I am NOT looking for a syntax that unix commands would understand or that programs would be able to open directly. The syntax does not need to explain how to access those files. (However, these are the obvious next steps.)

Thanks.

Comment: There can't be a directory with same name as a file in the same place.

Comment: True. Bad example. I will correct. There are probably other reasons that syntax won't just work, which I am sure I will think of shortly!

Comment: That syntax should work fine.